# BitBucket Cloud: Enable Auto Fork Sync

Tags: bitbucket

How can I enable auto fork syncing on BitBucket cloud ? I cant find the option and have to manually keep the fork updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While originally I found this article, it seems this only applies to their server product: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/keeping-forks-synchronized-776639961.html

This article indicates that its a process you will need to manage manually on local:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html

> After you fork a repository, the original repository is likely to continue to evolve as other users commit changes to it.  These changes do not appear in your fork. However, you can pull these changes into your fork later by syncing changes locally from the command line.

While this describes pulling upstream manually, you could probably script something to do this more automatically for your purposes. If I end up doing something like this for our team, I'll update this answer with more details or perhaps someone else will do the same.